# Cumulative Update

Tags: query, cumulative-update, service-pack

Does April 2016 CU for SharePoint 2013 contain all the fixes and features after Service Pack 1 release?

Actually I'm consolidating a list of fixes and features added since SharePoint 2013 SP1.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114938

Comment: Yes it does contain all fixes post SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Cumulative Updates are cumulative (contain all fixes) since the previous Service Pack/supported version (e.g. some CUs support both SP1 and March 2013 CU (baseline)).

Comment: Many thanks for your reponse. "Improvements and issues that this cumulative update fixes" section in the below URL contains a list of fixes.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3114938                                                       Are these the fixes added newly to April 2016 CU or its all the fixes post SP1? Any idea?

Comment: The KBs only address the fixes contained within that particular patch. You would need to compile a list of all fixes from May 2014 to current to determine 'everything' that has been fixed.